# How do I convert this ggplot2 bar plot to a line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with a discrete, ordered factor on the x-axis. I'd like to change the rendering from a bar graph to a line graph (in the style of `geom_freqpoly`). I can't use `geom_freqpoly` straight because I already have my data aggregated, and I don't know how to change the statistic from `stat = "bin"` to `stat = "identity"`. How can I make this happen?

Here's the data:

```
temp <- structure(list(wday = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), splitter = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), N = c(250245, 
40845, 209685, 45946, 200983, 49403, 142869, 52212, 88589, 48175, 
51061, 25317, 84012, 7994), price1 = c(22.79, 70.20, 35.92, 87.66, 
48.98, 55.37, 22.56, 88.50, 26.12, 63.29, 35.88, 73.79, 33.12, 82.80
)), .Names = c("wday", "splitter", "N", "price1"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

And here's the plot:

```
ggplot(melt(temp,id.vars = c("wday","splitter")), 
  aes(x = wday, y = value, fill = splitter)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

[image]

Though I would think the following code would work, it does not:

```
ggplot(melt(temp,id.vars = c("wday","splitter")), 
  aes(x = wday, y = value, colour = splitter)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a missing group aesthetic. The function `geom_line` uses the factors as the default grouping variables (here, `wday` and `splitter`), and so each group is a single data point. Specifying the grouping in `aes` renders the lines as desired:

```
ggplot(melt(temp,id.vars = c("wday","splitter")), 
  aes(x = wday, y = value, colour = splitter, group = splitter)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

[image: Now with lines!]

Comment: You can use the `geom_line` instead of `geom_path` to avoid having to sort the data beforehand: `tmp2 <- temp[sample(dim(temp)[1], dim(temp)[1]), ]; ggplot(melt(tmp2, id.vars=c('wday', 'splitter')), aes(x = wday, y = value, group = splitter, fill = splitter, color = splitter)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")`.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand why `geom_line` didn't work for me before. I didn't set `group` in my aesthetics. I'll edit my question & answer.